# Manipulating AutoGenerated Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and bind it to a datasource with unknown columns.

When I simply bind it to a datagrid all works find and all is bound.

But I cannot find anyway to treat columns based on their value.

I found out I can do like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        DateTime x;
        var res =DateTime.TryParse(e.Row.Cells[i].Text,out x);
        if (res)
        {
            TextBox text = new TextBox();
            text.Text =  e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Clear();
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(text);
        }
    }
}
```

but thats extreamly ugly

is there any way I can create a DateTime to Textbox convertor and tell my datagrid to use it for databinding?

**I am going to change the contorl from textbox to datepicker later on, this is only test mode..**

Answer (score 0):

Outside of very, very basic data binding scenarios you're going to find that you need to turn off `AutoGenerateColumns`, set up [`TemplateField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx) elements for many (or most) columns, and use the [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event.

I'm sorry that you find the pattern ugly, but *auto-generate* will do just that and no more; you don't have control over the values when the grid is handling creating columns and wiring up values for you.

Comment: but what do i do if I don't know the template? and RowDataBound seems to happen after row was already built so its doublework... :(

Comment: I aggree with Yuck and in my opinion the auto generated columns are an performance issue too

Comment: in my current I have a DataGrid with >15 columns and it took a few seconds to generate the columns...